# Area Chart with non-mixed positive and negative axis

Tags: charts, javafx, javafx-8

Good morning!! I'm new to javafx charts, what im trying to do is the following, but in a single chart:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/8uF5k.jpg

The input are two arrays, one with positive values, and the other with negative values. When I mix both arrays into a single chart, this is what I get:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/dOV12.jpg

I also tried to set the color of the second data set to transparent color, with no luck.

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Could you be a bit more explicit about what you want to change about your second chart?

Comment: I want the darker orange color to go away, I want transparent on top, and transparent on the bottom. Kinda like the first one, but into a single chart. Thanks!

Comment: This looks like this [known bug](https://javafx-jira.kenai.com/browse/RT-40114). It is (apparently) fixed in the latest pre-release. I would recommend checking to see if it works as you want on the [latest prerelease version](https://jdk8.java.net/download.html). That version is scheduled to be officially released in August 2015.

Comment: You are completely right! the new prerelease fixed my issue!

Answer (score 0):

As James_D mentioned, my problem was solved using the new prerelease of java! now it's paining the negative side of my area chart properly!